# Import и область видимости

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Есть файл main.py и funcs.py.

Почему я не могу так делать?

*main.py*

```
import pygame
from funcs import *

display = pygame.display.set_mode()

def main():
     change_background()

main()
```

*funcs.py*

```
def change_background():
      display.change_background(255,255,255)
```

NameError: name 'display' is not defined

Comment: Добавляя область видимости `funcs` в глобальную область видимости `main`, Вы не влияете на область видимости `funcs`, поэтому `display` так и остаётся неинициализированной.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Но как мне тогда быть, если мне нужно использовать `display` в `funcs`?

Comment: Передайте как аргумент (**идеальный вариант**). Или импортируйте явно (**плохой вариант**): `from main import display`, но тогда Вам нужно будет в `main` добавить `if __name__ == '__main__':`, чтобы не возникло проблем с вызовом функции (которая в этом момент ещё не определена).

Comment: и ещё ошибку исправьте возле `def main:`. Круглые скобки пустые отсутствуют

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут стоит показать весь файл `funcs.py`. В данном куске кода в функции `change_background()` не определено сущности `display`.

Если используется сущность из `main.py`, то в функции `change_background` стоит ожидать аргумент на вход и использовать его.

*main.py*

```
import pygame
from funcs import *

display = pygame.display.set_mode()

def main():
     change_background(display)
```

*funcs.py*

```
def change_background(dsp):
      dsp.change_background(255,255,255)
```

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе нет всей необходимой информации, но преположу, что вы хотите использовать объект `display` из библиотеки pygame внутри функции `change_background`.

Область видимости работает по другому. Когда запускается функция, то она видит только те переменные которые получила в качестве параметров или которые создала локально. Есть способ получить доступ к глобальной переменной модуля используя ключевое слово **global**, но этот способ имеет свои явные недостатки из-за невозможности полного контроля за состояниями переменных.

То что вы пытаетесь реализовать делается проще. Во время вызова функции передавайте в нее те переменные которые вы бы хотели видеть в локальной области видимости:

```
import pygame
from funcs import *

display = pygame.display.set_mode()

def main():
    # теперь переменная будет доступна функции
    change_background(display)  

main()
```